# Does postman support saving the collection runner?

Tags: postman

For example, I select some requests from a collection, order them as I wish, then can I just save all the requests along with the ordering, configuration, etc, so I can easily run again? I don't find any 'Save' button on the 'Run Collection' page.

Comment: No, you need to arrange requests in collection, not in runner.

Comment: OK.I don't agree with this design. But I don't see anything else that I can do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who might be seeking the same goal, Postman has this beta feature called 'Flow'. It's still not full-fledged and not very convenient to use. But it can do things.

Answer (score 1):

To save a test run in Postman and re-import it later, follow these steps:

Open Postman and make sure you have an active Postman account.

Create a new collection or open an existing collection to store your test runs.

Create a test script to suit your requirements in the collection or use an existing script.

After running the requests and running the tests, click the Tests tab for each request to view the test results.

The Tests tab allows you to see test scripts and test results. Copy the entire test script for each request.

Open a text editor or note-taking application and create a new file.

Paste the copied test script into a file and save it with an appropriate name and file extension ".json". For example: "request1_tests.json".

Repeat steps 5-7 for each request in your collection, saving the test script to a separate file. All test scripts are now stored in separate JSON files.

To import a saved test run back into Postman:

Open Postman and navigate to the collection where you want to import your test runs.

For requests in collections, click the Test tab.

Delete the existing test script (if any) for this request.

Open the appropriate saved test script file in a text editor. Copy the entire contents of the saved test script file.

Paste the copied content into the Test tab of your request in Postman.

Save your request.

Repeat steps 2-7 for each request to import the corresponding saved test script.

By following these steps, you can save your test runs as separate JSON files and import them back into Postman as needed.

Comment: Please cite your sources.

Comment: This answer looks like it was generated by an AI (like ChatGPT), not by an actual human being. You should be aware that [posting AI-generated output is officially **BANNED** on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831). If this answer was indeed generated by an AI, then I strongly suggest you delete it before you get yourself into even bigger trouble: **WE TAKE PLAGIARISM SERIOUSLY HERE.** Please read: [Why posting GPT and ChatGPT generated answers is not currently allowed](https://stackoverflow.com/help/gpt-policy).